# PHP Cassandra Timeuuid constructor hits Integer Limit (32bit)

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax, timeuuid, datastax-php-driver

I am using cassandra timeuuid in my project. But unable to create timeuuid due to integer limits.

```
$time = time();

$tS = new Cassandra\Timeuuid($time);
echo("Time Stamp : " . $time       . "</br>");
echo("Time UUID  : " . $tS         . "</br>");
echo("UUID TS    : " . $tS->time() . "</br>");
```

If I run above code I am getting following result.

```
Time Stamp : 1519110425
Time UUID : 07e0a090-2ba3-11b2-a264-4f5a3b4facaa
UUID TS : 1519110
```

This means that Timeuuid constructor expects timestamp in milliseconds. But if I try to pass the parameter in milliseconds, it is hitting the integer limit for my php (32bit).

```
$time = time();

$tS = new Cassandra\Timeuuid($time * 1000);
echo("Time Stamp : " . $time       . "</br>");
echo("Time UUID  : " . $tS         . "</br>");
echo("UUID TS    : " . $tS->time() . "</br>");
```

Getting following error for the above code.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Cassandra\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid argument - integer or string expected in testFile.php:9 Stack trace: #0 testFile.php(9): Cassandra\Timeuuid->__construct(1519110640000) #1 {main} thrown in testFile.php on line 9
```

Since it is above the integer limit it is getting casted to float.

Any idea how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation states](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/php-driver/1.3/api/Cassandra/class.Timeuuid/#methods) that `Cassandra\Timeuuid` should receive integer that you get from `time` function.  Looking into source code of driver it really looks that it expects the value in seconds, and all multiplication then happens inside the C++ driver.

For me it looks like the error in the driver, so please file the issue against it [at JIRA](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/PHP/issues).